# ng-repeat and ng-href - when should it update?

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue where a value in an object in a list is changing, but the change is not being reflected in ng-href.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='tabrow docRow'>
    <span data-ng-repeat='f in dp.source.files'>
        <span class='linkedDoc' >
            <a class='attachedCaption' target='_blank'
               data-ng-href='{{f.vpath}}'>{{f.caption}}
                <img class='attachedSrc' data-ng-src='{{ f.vimg }}'/>
            </a>

        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have a watch on dp.source, and when it changes a call a function that loops through each f in dp.source.files and adds v.img and v.path.

vimg is updated before the callback in the watch exits.  vpath is updated asynchronously, maybe a second or two after the callback completes.  Since it is updated in an asynch call, I use $apply.

```
$scope.$watch('dp.source', function() {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < $scope.dp.source.files.length; idx++) {
            var f = $scope.dp.source.files[idx];
            f.vimg = _ev.imgMapper(dataProvider.imgMap, f.path);  <--- immediate
            f.vpath = '#';
            attachService.getURL(f);  <-- asynch call that updates f.vpath
        }
    }
```

attachService:

```
myObj.getURL = function(obj) {
    syncService.getURL(obj, function(url) {  <-- asynch return
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            obj.vPath = url;
        });
    });
};
```

vimg is present on the rendered page immediately, while the change in vpath is NEVER reflected on the page.

What am I missing?

To be clear, I have verified that the variable f.vpath IS getting updated.

Comment: Created (my first) jsfiddle that shows that it SHOULD work.  Hmmm [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ed4becky/c2CPp/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG is was a spelling error!

the HTML expects f.vpath and attachService updated obj.vPath

It was that simple